# python list as function parameter

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I was attempting to get this function called fizz_count that takes a list x as input and returns the count of the string “fizz” in that list to work. But the code always returns 1.

code so far:

```
def fizz_count(x): 
    count = 0 
    for item in x:
        if str(item).lower() == "fizz": 
            count += 1 

    return count
```

so when `fizz_count(["fizz","buzz","fizz"])` is called the code should return 2.

Comment: works fine here? maybe some issue previously with the formatting...

Comment: I ran your code and got 2..

Comment: Works for me. Check your formatting maybe something with indents ??

Comment: Is it possible that in your _real_ code, you've got the `return count` indented so it's inside the `for` or `if`, instead of after both as you have it here? Or that the `count = 0` is inside the loop instead of before it? Either of those would cause your problem.

Comment: Is this an exact copy of what your actual code looks like?

Comment: This question is offtopic, because questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it, and this question lacks the last one part, "to reproduce".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a nifty built-in python function called `count` that actually does exactly what you're looking for:

```
def fizz_count(x): 
    return x.count('fizz')
```

Whenever in doubt about python, consult [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

JaredPar makes a valid point, if you want this to be case-agnostic, then you do have to use a list-comprehension here. Modified code (with added utility):

```
def fizz_count(x, search_string, case_insensitive=False):
    if case_insensitive:
        x = [item.lower() for item in x]
    return x.count(search_string)
```

Comment: The OP's original question would essentially do a case agnostic count while this is case specific.

Comment: @JaredPar Good point, edited for completeness and niceness.

Answer (score 2):

It works perfectly fine for me.

As @Slater Tyranus writes, use of course `list.count` -> `fizzes.count('fizz')`. If you want to do some more sophisticated counting (like case insenstive), list comprehensions might help you.

```
>>> fizzes = ["fizz","buzz","fizz"]
>>> len([f for f in fizzes if lower(f) == 'fizz'])
2
```

Or (thanks @iCodez):

```
>>> sum(1 for f in fizzes if lower(f) == 'fizz')
```

---

### For performance junkies (**Python 2.7**)

```
>>> from timeit import timeit                                              
>>> fizzes = [u"fizz", u"buzz"] * 10000                                    
>>> def fizz_for():                                                        
...     count = 0                                                          
...     for item in fizzes:                                                
...         if item == u"fizz":                                            
...             count += 1                                                 
...     return count
... 
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_for()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)    
1.393934965133667
>>> fizz_len = lambda: len([f for f in fizzes if f == u'fizz'])            
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_len()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)    
1.3358290195465088
>>> fizz_sum = lambda: sum(1 for f in fizzes if f == u'fizz')              
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_sum()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)    
1.7232561111450195
>>> fizz_count = lambda: fizzes.count(u'fizz')                             
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_count()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)  
0.44240689277648926
```

### Python 3.3 (looks quite the other way around):

```
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_for()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)   
1.5867065230013395
>>> fizz_len = lambda: len([f for f in fizzes if f == 'fizz'])      
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_len()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)  
1.2898265199983143
>>> fizz_sum = lambda: sum(1 for f in fizzes if f == 'fizz')          
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_sum()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)
1.5955777620001754
>>> fizz_count = lambda: fizzes.count('fizz')             
>>> timeit('__main__.fizz_count()', setup='import __main__', number=1000)   
0.3196232570007851
```

### Conclusions

- Use `list.count` if possible.
- It's very interesting that the on of the for loop in Python 2.7 is faster than a `sum`.
- Using `unicode` makes it ~30% slower (Not in the results, checked it locally).

Comment: This could be a bit inefficient cause you have to create a list just to then count it, instead of not having to create a list at all.

Comment: A better approach would be: `sum(1 for f in fizzes if f == 'fizz')`

Comment: @iCodez `fizzes.count('fizz')` ?

Comment: In any case, this answer is complete overkill for something so trivial (-1).

Comment: @arshajii A -1 for such a mundane reason?

Comment: @glglgl I think it's dangerous (for lack of a better term) to get Python newcomers into the habit of using list comprehensions where they are unneeded. This answer overcomplicates what should be a very simple problem.

Comment: @arshajii - Yes, `list.count` is a lot better for lists.  I should have said that.  However, I fail to see the reason for building a whole function just to call `list.count`.  At least the `sum` solution will work with any iterable.

Comment: @iCodez There are potential valid reasons for writing such a function. In terms of future development, if the search string changed from `'fizz'` to something else, then it would only need to be changed in the one function, whereas if `.count()` was called directly it could have to be changed in many places, which could lead to bugs. Granted you can do the same thing with a constant holding the search string, but we can make the same argument for the search criteria/algorithm changing as well.

Comment: @iCodez the count function also works with any iterable for which count makes sense (not sets).

Comment: @iCodez A function being short and relying on build in functionality shouldn't be a reason not to write it.

Comment: Ok, I concede.  You both have made some good points here.  As of now, I officially endorse the accepted answer (+1) over my solution using `sum`. :)

Comment: @Claudiu: It's not inefficient, I just made a few calculations because of your comment.

Comment: @DaveHalter: oh, interesting! even for 10 million elements, the `len` version is faster than the `for` version. didn't expect that. interesting how much overhead the generator brings to this in the `sum` version.